# Coin Toss- Probability of conditional event

Tags: probability

With a simultaneous toss of 5 coins,what would be the probability of getting exactly 2 heads if at least one comes up a head?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried / where you are getting stuck. You will find that people on this site will be significantly faster to help you if you do that; that way, we know exactly what help you need.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, there'd be $2^5=32$ possible outcomes. How many are there if we require that at least one comes up head, i.e. "all tails" is forbidden? How many of these are successful, i.e. with exactly *two out of five* showing head?